# Learning AngualrJS using Visual studio

Tags: asp.net, .net, angularjs, visual-studio-2013

I am learning AngularJS, using Visual Studio. I am not web developer, so I am not sure which template to use, there are multiple templates and its add a lot more things which add to un necessary complexity

Can you guide on which template to use learning AngularJS?

Comment: File > New Website > Visual Basic | Visual C# > ASP.NET Empty Web Site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File > New Website > Visual Basic | Visual C# > ASP.NET Empty Web Site